# php mail() Goes to spam but when sent via SMTP Server it works fine?

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail, postfix-mta

I am currently setting up my webserver so then i can send emails via PHP Code, the problem i have is that the emails sent via php mail() always send to my gmail spam where as when im sending emails via the SMTP Server the same VPS has on it on Gmail it dont send to spam.

Is their anyone that can help with this?

### Updates:

Sending Via Ryan@Ryanteck.org.uk & Noreply@Mc-Serverlist.co.uk For PHP Mail() (Same happens with ryan@ryanteck.org.uk)

When Sent Via PHP Mail() Or Webmin Email It Sends To Spam

When Sent Via SMTP Server Via Gmail it sends ok

PHP Mail Raw Message :
http://pastebin.com/TP2UfDP7  (This is the Noreply@Mc-Serverlist.co.uk)

Webmin Email System :
http://pastebin.com/2VWvDd7v

Gmail SMTP : 
http://pastebin.com/wgewGnmk

Comment: Needs more info, e.g. what sender addresses are used in the two scenarios.

Comment: The headers as received in both instances would help.

Comment: Spam filters detect spam messages by checking the message body, sender address, reply address, subject, etc. You may want to check them (and also provide more information regarding to these parameters in your question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your vps doesn't have rDNS configured and the HELO points to a different ip. inconsistencies in HELO and missing rDNS trigger many spamfilters.

> Received: from ryanteck.org.uk ([95.154.250.75])
>
> Host 75.250.154.95.in-addr.arpa. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
>
> ryanteck.org.uk has address 95.154.250.165

Set a HELO Hostname whose A-Record points back to your VPS and configure the rDNS (PTR) to the same hostname.

Example:

- Create a new A-Record 'vps.ryanteck.org.uk 95.154.250.75'
- Set the HELO to 'vps.ryanteck.org.uk'
- Set the reverse DNS (PTR) for 75.250.154.95 to vps.ryanteck.org.uk

Also your senderdomains have somewhat strange "TXT" records:

```
dig txt mc-serverlist.co.uk +short 
"95.154.250.165"
dig txt ryanteck.org.uk +short
"95.154.250.165"
```

you may want to change these into correctly formatted SPF records, eg.

```
v=spf1 ip4:95.154.250.165 ip4:95.154.250.75 ~all
```

Comment: I changed the main IP back into 95.154.250.165 as 95.154.250.75 was the secondary one,

Comment: 95.154.250.165 doesn't have rDNS either

Comment: if there is no option to manage rDNS in your vps control panel you'll have to contact the vps provider and tell them to set the rDNS entry for your IP.

Comment: I just changed it to 165.250.154.95, I think thats correct?

Comment: Should be changed to 165.250.154.95, as it shows that in VPS Panel.

Comment: My Domain Company Should have made the changes now :D

Comment: Now the mail message is : http://pastebin.com/8iJYCdj4

Comment: your SPF record is ok now ("SPF pass") , but your rDNS (PTR) should not point to an ip, it should point to a HOSTNAME. eg. 
165.250.154.95.in-addr.arpa PTR ryanteck.org.uk

Comment: your dns settings look ok now

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mail('my@gmail.com', 'my subject', 'my text', 'From: noreply@myweb.com', '-f noreply@myweb.com');
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the `-f noreply@myweb.com` parameter, as described in [PHP ref](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

> For example, this can be used to set the envelope sender address when using sendmail with the -f sendmail option.
>
> The user that the webserver runs as should be added as a trusted user to the sendmail configuration to prevent a 'X-Warning' header from being added to the message when the envelope sender (-f) is set using this method. For sendmail users, this file is /etc/mail/trusted-users.