# PHP emails via SMTP: what is HELO, how to setup to avoid being SPAM

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer, spam

On a website with about 1300 Users I've set up that emails for confirming your email address, etc are being sent with phpmailer via a gmail account (google smtp), which worked very well for the first 2 month.

Now, recently a bigger and bigger amount of users complain they do not receive any emails anymore, not even in the Spam folder.

While I have no problem receiving any when I try it myself, I found that it especially concerns certain providers (or let's say a wide variety of providers, just not gmail itself).

Then I found this article: [php mail() Goes to spam but when sent via SMTP Server it works fine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8525724/php-mail-goes-to-spam-but-when-sent-via-smtp-server-it-works-fine)

I do not really understand what Gryphius (the accepted answer) talks about. I've read in the Google Guidelines for avoiding SPAM (don't remember how they are called exactly), about HELO and A-records, but don't know what they are. Could anybody explain me what it is and how to do that?

What else can be done to send emails from shared hosting and ensure they most all reach their recipients?

Thank you very much already in advance for your help!

UPDATE: This information I found in the header, what could you tell from this?

> X-Acl-Warn: X-DNSBL-JUNKEMAILFILTER
>   X-Spam-Score: -0.3

Comment: Have you checked that your not in any lists? http://www.spamhaus.org/lookup/

Comment: @LawrenceCherone: thx, what IP should you enter there?

Comment: your server IP, or the IP of the server sending your mail, you could check your mail header for this info or do a nslookup on your mx entry

Comment: Google SMTP has limits - are you exceeding those limits?

Comment: @robbie: oh, did not know that... :S what limits, do you have any idea? as said, it is maybe about 1300 users, so on times there might be 1500-2000 outgoing mails a day...?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone: OK, thank you so much. I've tried all of the listed IPs (because there are more than one line for "Received: by [--IP--] with SMTP id ..."), none of them is listed, everything green...

Comment: @Helmut http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=166852 - 2000 per day is your limit. I think that's your issue. (Not limit on external recipients as well)