# Email with attachments going to Spam folder - VPS Server

Tags: php, html-email

I'm trying to fix a issue. where email with attachments going to Spam Folder. Previously i came across similar issues & those are HTML email.but here its with attachment. if i did not add the "From" in the header email is coming to inbox (username@vps.mydomain.com). Actually i'm tying to change this sender email so that it wont go to SPAM. i have managed to change the "From" in header but still it goes to SPAM.

Also i tried "-f" concept, still it goes to SPAM.

Here is the headers & Message with attachment

```
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";  
//$header .= 'From: Move <info@ccc.com>' . "\r\n";  
//$header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
$message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n\r\n";
$message .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$message .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";  
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
$message .= $emailtext."\r\n\r\n";
$message .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";    
$message .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
$message .= "--".$uid."--";   

if (mail($email, $subject, $message, $header, "-finfo@ccc.com")) {
```

Comment: Maybe, this also depends on the subject/title and content.

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit I tied changing the Message(Paintext) & Subject also. Still it goes to spam

Comment: The reason is, you're inserting header information into your `message`. Change all of your `$message` to `$header` while concatenating properly, then add `$message=""` and keep going.

Comment: @Fred. Yes i noticed that i tried a new sample given here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519588/send-php-html-mail-with-attachments

Comment: @Fred its also going to SPAM Folder. in that example they have added those content types to header which was wrong in mine.

Comment: @Parthi04 it's going to Spam because of that. Have a look at my example below.

Comment: @Fred Here my scenario is I have to send the HTML email with attachments. i tried few examples which looks similar to your code below. HTML email is fine. once i think about the attachments.facing this issue.

Comment: @Parthi04 I think I may have something for you, give me a few minutes.

Comment: @Fred Example in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519588/send-php-html-mail-with-attachments. if i comment the From & reply to header. email is coming to inbox. once i un comment that then it goes to SPAM

Comment: @Parthi04 Are you trying to send ONE attachment or many at a time?

Comment: It is coming to spam because of your VPS host. Modern email systems use global service for IP authorization and your IP does not seem to be authorized, why? Because 97% of emails are spam and so everyone could setup their SMTP service and bomb email services. So your way is to use some paid certificated SMTP service :] + attachment = 100% spam.

Comment: @Parthi04 Found a few articles/answers that could be of help. I Google'd "mail goes to SPAM VPS" in case you wish to further your research. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8530251/1415724 and http://forums.deftechgroup.com/showthread.php?t=3685 <= links in there too. And http://forums.cpanel.net/f43/mail-marked-spam-tried-everything-157225.html and http://forums.zpanelcp.com/thread-4606-post-38890.html#pid38890 I wish you well :) Cheers (*Peace*)

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT #2: (PDF attachment)

You will need to enter your `$_POST` variables, but if you try this as is, including the PDF file you wish to send, will run on its own. Change all instances of `file.pdf` in the code to the file name you wish to attach, as well as your Email address. (**TESTED**)

```
<?php
$sendto = "email@example.com";
$message = "Message here\r\n Hello, this is a test!!";

$filename = "file.pdf";
$handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');
$contents = fread($handle,filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);
$encoded = chunk_split(base64_encode($contents));

$seperator = md5(uniqid(time()));
$from = '"First Last" <username@domain.com>';
$header = '';
$header .= "From: $from\r\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type:"." multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$seperator\";\r\n";


$body.= "--$seperator\r\n";
$body.= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n";
$body.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\n";
$body.= $message."\r\n\n";

$body.= "--$seperator\r\n";
$body.= "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=\"file.pdf\"\r\n";
$body.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$body.= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"file.pdf\"\r\n\n";
$body.= $encoded."\r\n";
$body.= "--$seperator--\r\n";

mail($sendto,$subject, $body, $header);
?>
```

Comment: form VPS host - its coming to inbox without attachement but attached PDF is not coming in email.

Comment: @Parthi04 Ah so it's a PDF then, that could make a difference. I have another script for that. Let you know in a few minutes. Will clear my answer with new code.

Comment: @Parthi04 See my Edit #2. Tested

Comment: i think VPS Host is making these issue. i tried few sample code.none of them are working. Everything goes to SPAM

Comment: @Parthi04 I tend to think so too. Sorry my code didn't work. I can delete my answer if you wish.

Comment: Thanks for trying it along with me. Don't delete it. if someone face same issue & if this answer solves it, we might consider this answer as reference.

Comment: @Parthi04 You're very much welcome. I will do as you wish then. I hope you resolve your issue, cheers!

Comment: @Parthi04 Cheers and have a look at the links I included in a comment in your question. (*Peace*) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271775/email-with-attachments-going-to-spam-folder-vps-server/18272454?noredirect=1#comment26802228_18271775