# PHP mail() classified as spam from Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: php, email, ubuntu-12.04, spam

I have set up a Ubuntu server to host Magento CE, which works fine apart from sending out emails.

The emails are sent, but are picked up by our internal spam filter (on a Win2k Exchange mail server running Exclaimer) before making it to the outside world.

I created a test web page and I can see it's not just Magento, it's any mail that is sent with php mail().

I am using postfix to relay to our mailserver.

If I send a test email using telnet localhost 25 then my emails get sent out fine with the proper headers, it's only if sent by PHP mail() that emails don't have the proper headers as picked up by exclaimer:

```
Received-SPF: pass (Exclaimer Mail Utilities: "this" network is always allowed.) client-ip=0.0.0.0; envelope-from=support@MYCOMPANY.co.uk; helo=;
X-ExAntiSpamFlags: LOCAL_IP IP_NO_PTR HELO_NOT_FQDN IP_PTR_NOT_FQDN SMTP_FROM_NOT_EQUAL_822_FROM SPF_PASS RECIPIENT_NOT_IN_AD 
X-SPF-Result: 3
```

I have had a look at this Q&A ([php mail() Goes to spam but when sent via SMTP Server it works fine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8525724/php-mail-goes-to-spam-but-when-sent-via-smtp-server-it-works-fine)) however that scenario uses a VPS which I am not.

I can see that the helo is set to nothing in the "spam" message, but do not know where I should be setting the helo for PHP mail().

I tried adding headers to my php like so:

```
<?php

 $headers .="Reply-To: OUR Sales <sales@MYCOMPANY.co.uk>\r\n";
 $headers .="Return-Path: OUR Sales <sales@MYCOMPANY.co.uk>\r\n";
 $headers .="From: OUR Sales <sales@MYCOMPANY.co.uk>\r\n";
 $headers .="client-ip: 192.XXX.XXX.XXX\r\n";
 $headers .="helo: UBUNTUSVR.MYCOMPANY.co.uk\r\n";
 $headers .="hostname: UBUNTUSVR.MYCOMPANY.co.uk\r\n";
 $headers .="Organization: Boxes from OURDirect\r\n";
 $headers .="MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
 $headers .="Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
 $headers .="X-priority: 3\r\n";
 $headers .="X-Mailer: PHP". phpversion() ."\r\n";
echo mail("externalemail@hotmail.com","my subject","my message",$headers)
?>
```

This didn't help!

I guess I could set Exclaimer to allow emails from the Ubuntu box, however I suspect they'll just end up getting caught out by someone elses spam filter and I'd rather send the emails out properly.

Where do I make changes so that PHP mail() sends an email with the correct helo and client-ip settings given that my machine has the correct FQDN and has no prob with telnet SMTP mail?

Comment: This is not a solution, but I'd just stop using `mail()` function altogether. Save all the trouble and use PHPMailer or SwiftMailer — they're far better.

Comment: something like Madrill would make you life much easier - sending mail  with a decent delivery rate is not a trivial task

Comment: Has a free plugin http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ebizmarts-magemonkey-official-mailchimp-and-mandrill-integration.html and the service is free up to 12k emails a month

Comment: This has nothing to do with the lib or function you use to send mails. Just read the reasons why it is flagged spam and improve the configuration of your mailserver. Try `ehlo` instead of `helo`, and give your ubuntu server a FQDN instead of `localhost`

Comment: Using another lib will still result in the same problems. Some pointers are: Create a reverse-lookup entry in your DNS for your server. Ensure your mail server is not an OpenRelay.

Comment: If you have a good mail server you want to relay to, either configure your local sendmail to use that one OR configure PHP to use SMTP to that server OR use a lib that makes it easy to send via SMTP (like PHPMailer or SwiftMailer)

Comment: Make sure to specify DNS entries for IPv4 and IPv6.  I ran across this where I had the v4 one set, but not v6.

Comment: Thanks to all for the suggestions. I tried setting ehlo rather than helo in headers for mail(), that made no difference (and machine already had FQDN). I didn't actually have a DNS entry in /etc/network/interfaces for IPv4 (IPv6 is disabled) but adding it didn't make any difference. My initial thought was that I would still have probs using another lib to send, but had a go anyway and PHPMailer sends my emails properly! Just need to work out how to use it with Magento now. I may have a look at Madrill as is has the plugin.

Comment: @Amal Murali Your comment may not have been a solution to the particular question that I asked but seems to be the solution to my problem!

Comment: @user3733854: Awesome. I too found that out the hard way!

Comment: Just in case anyone else out there is having trouble with getting emails to send properly with Magento and is reading this - the solution to this for me was installing the free Magento extension SMTP Pro  - http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smtp-pro-email-free-custom-smtp-email.html It was easy to install and configure.